# Apache/CentOS 7: /var/www/html/ owned by root but created files owned by apache - how do I resolve this?

Tags: php, apache, chown, centos7, chgrp

I have a fresh, unmodified install of Apache on CentOS 7. I notice that when I look at the folder permissions for /var/www/html it and it's content is owned by apache. When a file is created, however, its owner and group is Apache.

Though html is owned by root:root, should all of the contents be owned by apache:apache? or [user]:apache with that user belonging to the Apache group? How should I go about this?

**Edit:**
Another question - do I *want* to change this? I do not have a very good understanding of file ownership in Linux systems but it seems with this configuration that the newly created files (apache:apache) are prevented from taking action against files that already exist (root:root). This *should* prevent PHP hacks from being able to manipulate any existing files, right? Is this just the illusion of security though?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file and search for user and group [e.g. User apache Group apache]. Those are the owners by default. In your website there is no need too add write permissions for files and folders assigned to user:group, but you can set readable by owner and others in order to be accessible via web.

Updated answer:
The main reason DirectoryRoot (/var/www/html) owned by root is security. You can leave root as owner of files and set group to apache. Regarding security you make sure apache group has read-only access to files [-> One first meassure]. The security is not an illusion. While files are owned by root and do not have rw access from others, it is hard for external attackers to gain write access to files [because this is the most common way to hijack a site].

Comment: Thanks, since originally posting I began to question whether or not I should change this. Would you mind taking a look at my edit? Thanks again!

Comment: See updated answer. The security is not an illusion. While owned by root it is hard for external attackers to gain write access to files [because this is the most common way to hijack a site].

Comment: Thanks! I could ask questions all day about how this impacts PHP applications (drupal, magento, etc..) and the applications themselves ability to add/remove/manipulate files as needed but I think I'll see if I can find some linux lessons regarding file/directory permissions.

Comment: There are, as I can remember, some Magento, Joomla, Drupal howtos which explain folder and file permissions. Anyway, each platform has it's own rules. In Magento is a special need for some files like local.xml to be chmoded safely. Read some documentation regarding post install file and folder permissions. Good luck!